# Python pip install qibuild exception then I installed pip yet.

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, robotics, debian-based

I'm new on this forum and I will ask you to be friendly with my first publication. Thank you!!

So, here is my problem. I installed pip and now I try to install qibuild with it. But I've got a problem.
This is the command that I run:

```
pip install qibuild
```

And this the error that I have:

```
Downloading/unpacking qibuild
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in  main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 290, in run
requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle,bundle=self.bundle)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1178, in prepare_files
url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 194, in find_requirement
page = self._get_page(main_index_url, req)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_page
session=self.session,
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 694, in get_page
req, link, "connection error: %s" % exc, url,
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type SysCallError)

Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

I searched on the net and I didn't find anything like that. Someone have an idea of what I can do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the time on your system. Sometimes it so happens when your system time is inaccurate the pip installation fails. I have faced this issue once.

Change your system date to current date in accordance with your time zone ,
Hope this helps